# how to shorten the rebasing workflow?

Tags: git

Assume i have made 10 commits on myBranch (and myBranch is checked out).
I want to rebase with master and squash all commits.

our current workflow is ...

1. git checkout master
2. git fetch origin
3. git pull -r origin master
4. git checkout myBranch
5. git rebase -i master
6. git push -f origin myBranch

A total of 6 steps AND interactive rebase consoles to deal with too (not to mention the risk of force pushing).

Is there a shorter workflow that will have the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to update your local `master` branch if your goal is
simply to rebase against the upstream `master` branch.  You can replace these steps:

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git pull -r origin master
git checkout myBranch
git rebase -i master
```

With:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase -i origin/master
```

If you want to avoid the interactive rebase, you can do what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/5201642#5201642):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -m 'message for merged commit'
```

This resets the current branch to `origin/master` without affecting your working directory, and it leaves all of your changes staged in the index.  This means that the `git commit` will commit all of your changes in a single step.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do with your local commits is to squash them, you don't even need to do an interactive rebase. You can do it using `git reset --soft`, which is much more convenient:

`git reset --soft HEAD~10` #soft reset to 10 commits ago

`git commit -m "Message for the squashed commits"` #all your changes will be already added to the index at this point

Then you can rebase against the remote's `master` branch:

`git fetch origin`
`git rebase origin/master`

Note that squashing the commits is only safe if nobody (except you) has pulled these 10 commits from `myBranch` yet, otherwise you will rewrite history and you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch origin
git rebase -i origin/master
git push -f origin myBranch
```

or if you want to save the changing of the stanzas on all lines and want to use a completely new commit message

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit
git push -f origin myBranch
```

or if you want to save the changing of the stanzas on all lines and want to reuse the commit messages from all squashed commits

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
git push -f origin myBranch
```